# When do we say two sets are Disjoint?

Tags: general-topology

Is (1,2] and (2,3) Disjoint sets or (1,2) and (2,3) are Disjoint sets. I have confusion regarding whether we need to take the closure of one set and intersect it with other to get a empty set. Similarly do that for the other set to verify they are Disjoint or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual definition of two sets $A$ and $B$ being disjoint is that their intersection is empty. That is, $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Both of your examples are disjoint by this definition.

Answer (score 1):

Disjoint always means empty intersection. Sets that are disjoint from each others' closures (that is, $A \cap \bar{B} = \bar{A}\cap B = \emptyset$) are called *separated*. I'm not sure if there's a specific term for two sets whose closures do not intersect.